# Cauchy's Condensation Test for $f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ a decreasing sequence of positive terms, What are the conditions for a function $f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ satisfies that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \lneq \infty \;\;\text{if and only if}\;\; \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)a_{f(n)} \lneq \infty \;\text{?}$$

I know that if $M\in \mathbb{N}$ and $f(n)=M^n$ then

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \lneq \infty \;\;\text{if and only if}\;\;  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(M^n)a_{M^n} \lneq \infty $$

What else functions satisfy this property?

Comment: What does $ \lneq \infty $ mean?  Is it same as $<$?

Comment: Yes, it is the same as <

Comment: Personally, I think that the thing to look at should be $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (f(n+1)-f(n))a_{f(n)}$ rather than $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)a_{f(n)}$.